# Python doesn't show anything

Tags: python

It's my first Python program and my first excercise is that I just need to swap places in a tuple:

```
stamboom = [("Frans","Eefje"), ("Klaar","Eefje"), ("Eefje","Mattho"),
            ("Eefje","Salammbo"), ("Gustave","Mattho"), ("Gustave","Salambo")]
```

Is the tuple, and I need to swap Frans with Eefje (those are just names) and then swap the second tuple.

I read the whole data structure tutorial off Python and I thought I could do this like this:

```
#!/path/to/python

stamboom = [("Frans","Eefje"), ("Klaar","Eefje"), ("Eefje","Mattho"),
            ("Eefje","Salammbo"), ("Gustave","Mattho"), ("Gustave","Salambo")]

def switchplace(x): 
    stamboom[x], stamboom[x + 1] = stamboom[x + 1], stamboom[x]
    return stamboom

map(switchplace, range(0, len(stamboom)))
```

It doens't give syntax errors but it doesn't show anything.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To show something you have to `print` it.

Change the last line to:

```
print map(switchplace,range(0,len(stamboom)))
```

Answer (score 3):

That was very complicated code for a simple task. Check out something called list comprehension.

Change the code to:

```
stamboom = [("Frans","Eefje"), ("Klaar","Eefje"), ("Eefje","Mattho"),
            ("Eefje","Salammbo"), ("Gustave","Mattho"), ("Gustave","Salambo")]

stamboom = [(item[1], item[0]) for item in stamboom]
print stamboom
```

## Update

I saw your solution in the comment. I don't know if there are more premisses to the excersise that I'm not aware of. But I would probably do this instead:

```
def switchplace(x):
    return x[1], x[0]

stamboom = [("Frans","Eefje"),("Klaar","Eefje"),("Eefje","Mattho"), ("Eefje","Salammbo"),("Gustave","Mattho"),("Gustave","Salammbo")]

print map(switchplace, stamboom)
```

The iterable argument to map don't have to be a numeric range. It could be the list itself. But maybe I missed something and you already got it :)

Comment: Or even better: `stamboom = [(x2, x1) for x1, x2 in stamboom]`

Comment: Yes I know but the exercise sais it must be done with the map function from python. And the stamboom is given.

Comment: #!/path/to/python 
def switchplace(x) :
 print("\n ", stamboom[x])
 lijst = [stamboom[x][1],stamboom[x][0]]
 return lijst

stamboom = [("Frans","Eefje"),("Klaar","Eefje"),("Eefje","Mattho"), ("Eefje","Salammbo"),("Gustave","Mattho"),("Gustave","Salammbo")]

print(list(map(switchplace, range(0,6))))

Comment: If I understood the excerise right. There are probably easier ways to do it. I add an sample above :)

Answer (score 0):

Tuples are immutable in Python:

http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html